# Adding methods to already defined class

Tags: ruby, oop

Why can I add a new method to `String` class?

```
class String   
  def abc
    "hey"   
  end 
end

puts "jayanti".abc  #hey
puts "meow".abc     #hey
```

Can you guys also tell me what OOP concept this is? As in how could I relate this with the OOPS concepts normally taught.
Thanks again

Comment: It seems like you already know how. Your intention is not clear.

Comment: @sawa I meant why can I add a new method to another class? This shouldn't be allowed. Is it a Ruby specific thing? Is this an inheritance concept or something else?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: I mean I haven't seen this happening in other languages like C, C++, java etc

Comment: So what? Ruby is not C, C++, or java.

Comment: Welcome to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

So you're asking how this is possible.

In ruby everything is object (or almost). For example:

```
String.class # Class
```

The class of `String` is `Class`, so `String` is an instance of `Class`.

The ruby model object is not easy to understand at the first sight when you come from `C++` or `Java`.

When you do:

```
class String
  def abc
    "hey"
  end
end
puts "foo".abc #hey
```

You're reopening the class `String` and define a new instance method `abc`. You can also add a new method to the `String` class thanks to the keyword `self`, like this:

```
class String
  def self.abc
    "hey from class :)"
  end
end
puts String.abc #hey from class :)
```

Here, you're adding a `abc` method to the `String` object itself.

If you're interested to learn how ruby works in depth, there is a lot of book, one of my favorite is this one:https://www.amazon.co.uk/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Facets/dp/1941222129

as Tiago said, the class reopening method is called Monkey patching and you have to use it sparingly :)

**Previous answer:**

You can use the `self` keyword, like this:

```
class String
  def self.abc
    "hey from class :)"
  end
end

puts String.abc #hey from class :)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted :/ The question is: "How can I add a new method to String class?". Maybe that's not what he wanted to say but my answer is the right answer to this specific question.

Comment: I mean How is this possible? More like Why can I add.. I'll change it. As in I don't get the concept. Is this a inheritance concept or something else.

Comment: In fact, you can reopen a class in Ruby. In Java or C++, an object is an instance of a class and nothing more. In Ruby, a class is also an object :)

Comment: Here is a basic explanation of why and how: http://runtime-era.blogspot.fr/2012/12/reopen-and-modify-ruby-classes-monkey.html

Comment: Alright Thanks. So this isn't anything like Inheritance or some other oops concept right?

Comment: This still doesn't make much sense to me but still its the best answer and I just think I'll have to read about this stuff

Comment: You have written **The class of String is Class, so String is an instance of Class.** How is this related to the concept I was asking about? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, modules and classes can be modified during runtime. From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Module+Definition):

> A module may be reopened any number of times to add, change or remove functionality.

But you should only modify your own modules / classes:

> Reopening classes is a very powerful feature of Ruby, but it is best to only reopen classes you own. Reopening classes you do not own may lead to naming conflicts or difficult to diagnose bugs.

In particular, you should not alter Ruby's core classes.

Answer (score 0):

That technique is called Monkey Patching:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Love or hate it, it's useful specially for tests, think of Mocks/Stubs.